# Why write to file always double in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, writetofile

I writing some results to text file, and I recognized it starts to double the result, I don't know from when and where it happened.
I tried:

```
//test how manytime running the file writing:
int h = 0;
using (StreamWriter _testData = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/File.txt"), true))
{

     _testData.WriteLine(h); // Write the file.
}
h = h + 1;
```

And open the file I will see:

```
0
0
```

So I am very sure that it write to file twice, not the write file run two times (if run two times then the result would be : 0, 1.

I also tried:

```
int k = 0;
using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(Server.MapPath("~/File.txt")))
{

    sw.Write(k);

    sw.Close();
}
k=k+1;
```

But I also get in the file: 0 0
So why is it writing to file twice ? How to avoid it ?

Comment: I think were missing something here. There is NO other code as part of using and no other code inside using?

Answer (score 0):

You're re-creating the number each time by using a local variable here:

```
int h = 0;
```

Every time you write.. its writes `0`.. because you've told it to.

Perhaps what you really want.. is to load the last number and add one to that:

```
int h = 0;

if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/File.txt"))) {
    h = Convert.ToInt32(File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("~/File.txt"))
                        .Reverse()
                        .First()) + 1;
}

// h is now 0 if no file exists.. or that last number + 1 if the file did exist.
```

This obviously doesn't perform any error checking, but it should give you an idea.

Comment: I don't mind if it write 0 or whatever number. But it will write it twice I believe so. I think I call the write file only one but it write the output twice

Comment: I would have to see more code to confirm that. That certainly _does not happen_ for me. Perhaps you have two web requests happening?

Comment: So you see no problem about the method of calling the write file I mentioned above? How to know if my code is actually run twice and it makes the write file did it twice ?

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the top of the method that has this code. Debug it. If the breakpoint is hit twice.. you're calling it twice.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the second 0 because you are not clearing your file inbetween executions of your program. It is an odd set of circumstances that brought you to this result however. I believe you may have had this problem due to a combination of using the functions `Write()` and `WriteLine()` while not clearing the file inbetween executions. Using the function `WriteLine()` would have added the \n newline character to the file, and left the file pointer at that location on the second line. You then perhaps called the function `Write()` which then placed a 0 on the second line. Thus you have two 0's. I would recommend clearing the file each time you write to it unless you want to simply append to it.

To do this, you can initialize your StreamWriter inside of a using block that uses a file stream to set the fileMode to truncate rather than append:

```
int k = 0;
using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Truncate))
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        writer.Write(k);
    }
}
```